# Receiving a "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java

In my Java class, we're creating a connect 4 game. For now, we're just setting up the GUI. I am receiving the error on lines 13 and 14 
      " private ArrayListplayer;
        private Connect4Ui frame;"

and I'm receiving an error in the UI class on the GameListener line as well as the Panel line. I'm sure it's something simple, but this is our first few weeks of the intro course. Thanks a lot!

```
package connectfour;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author j_ortiz9688
 */

// connect 4 main 
public class ConnectFour {

    private ArrayList<Player>player;
    private Connect4Ui frame; 


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }

}
```

Ui Class

```
package userInterface;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


/**
 *
 * @author j_ortiz9688
 */
public class Connect4Ui extends JFrame {

    JMenuBar menuBar;  
    JMenu gameMenu;
    JMenuItem playerPlayer;
    JMenuItem playerComputer;
    JMenuItem computerComputer; 
    JMenuItem exit; 
    GameListener gameListener;
    Connect4Panel boardPanel;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't import the classes Player and Connect4Ui. They seem to be in other packages, so you should write something like:

```
import userInterface.Connect4Ui;
```

at the beginning of your ConnectFour-File

Comment: That worked for Connect4Ui but I'm receiving the redline error under <Player> still. Am I forgetting to import something for that?

Comment: Yes. You have to import that as well! In which package is Player? For example if you declared "package game;" in your Player-class you have to import it via `import game.Player;`

Comment: Ah I see, yes, the "Player" class is in a core package while the UI stuff is in another package. Makes sense, thank you very much!